# Validating URI, below redirect. Web App : Servlets Java

Tags: java

I have URL entered by users.

User can enter URI. [relative URI]

How can I validate that relative URI ?

EX: For absolute URI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.

User can enter "questions/ask".

Is there any ways read web.xml to validate uri.[Java web app]

Comment: Validate it in what way? That it exists? That it's a well-formed (but possibly non-existent) URI?

Comment: Yes.. i want to append http protocol if it is missing in user input urls. but i need to exclude reuri from appending http, as relative uri will break if http appended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- if you can verify whether the address actually exists, you can use:

  ```
  HttpURLConnection connection = 
       (HttpURLConnection) new URL(host + relativePart).openConnection();


  int status = connection.getResponseCode();
  ```

and see whether status 200 will be returned.

- if you want to check if the URI is well formed according to RFC 2396 - `new URI(uri)`

Comment: Thanks Bozha, for prompt reply. Basically I am looking for logic to append http protocol if user had missed out while entering URL. As URL can be Relative URI. I want to exclude the URI case for appending http protocol. I have 100+ URL/URI to draw in single page. I will appreciate any effective logic if you suggest.

Comment: well, you can check with `contains(..)` whether he has added the http://, and if not - prepend it.

Comment: true, but in case of relative uri this breaks. ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.
User can enter "questions/ask".

Comment: well, check for a `sitename.tld`. Or make it that the user choses whether the url is relative (to what?)